# slideToggle and click event does not work on new element

Tags: jquery, accordion

Why it does not close the table row when I click the second time?

```js
$("tr").on('click', function() {
  $("table").find(".new-element").remove();
  let el = $(this);
  var new_elements = "<tr class='new-element display-none'><td colspan='2'><div><ul>" +
    "<li><label>item1: </label><span>content1</span></li>" +
    "<li><label>item2: </label><span>content2</span></li>" +
    "</ul></div></td></tr>";
  $(el).after(new_elements);
  $(el).next().slideToggle("slow"); // means of new_elements
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>family</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>sum</td>
      <td>oven</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jak</td>
      <td>oven</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/11012345/1jvt69qh/#&togetherjs=e0AefgthCx

I even tried the code below, but it does not work.

```
$("tr.new_elements").click(function(){
  $(this).slideDown();
});
```

thank you

Comment: PS: `let el = $(this);` no need to wrap again jQuery into jQuery `$(el)`. Use only `el`. or, if you want to make notice that *el* ***is actually*** a jQuery ref, than use `$el` as variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Because you never close it ;)

When you click the same item, the item is removed by this:

```
$("table").find(".new-element").remove();
```

And put back by that:

```
let el = $(this);
var new_elements = "<tr class='new-element display-none'><td colspan='2'><div><ul>" +
"<li><label>item1: </label><span>content1</span></li>" +
"<li><label>item2: </label><span>content2</span></li>" +
"</ul></div></td></tr>";
$(el).after(new_elements);
$(el).next().slideToggle("slow");
```

What you need to do is check whether "this" and "that" is the same before you remove and recreate it. Well, at least that was the case before the fast closing toggle.

Before the toggle worked.

```
var active = $("table").find(".new-element");
var el = $(this);
if ($(el).next("tr").hasClass("new-element")) {
   $(active).remove();
   return false;
} else {
   $(active).remove();
}
```

With the toggle active:

```
$("table").find(".new-element").remove();
var new_elements = "<tr class='new-element display-none'><td colspan='2'><div><ul>" +
"<li><label>item1: </label><span>content1</span></li>" +
"<li><label>item2: </label><span>content2</span></li>" +
"</ul></div></td></tr>"; 
$(this).after(new_elements);
$(this).next().show();
$('.new-element').find("div").slideToggle('slow');
```

That's a pretty fast closing toggle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e54hu3rL/52/

That also takes away the need to do the checking to see whether the clicked item is the same as last, so the return false can be dropped.

Comment: In the first case, before the toggle worked, I was using the return false to exit execution and avoid putting the element back after removal which I wrote in my reply.. Then I realized that it was pretty easy to fix the toggle too and then I edited the first reply..  The story gets a bit blurry I guess, if you never read the first reply. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate a `tr`... Sadly, this is an element that cannot be animated.

But you can animate the inner `div`. See below:

```js
$("tr").on('click', function () {
  $("table").find(".new-element").remove();
  let el = $(this);
  var new_elements = "<tr class='new-element'><td colspan='2'><div class=' display-none'><ul>"
      + "<li><label>item1: </label><span>content1</span></li>"
      + "<li><label>item2: </label><span>content2</span></li>"
      + "</ul></div></td></tr>";
  el.after(new_elements);
  el.next().find("div").slideToggle("slow");     // means of new_elements
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.display-none{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>family</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>sum</td>
    <td>oven</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>jak</td>
    <td>oven</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```